# Core Plot - get data to fill up x axis screen space

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot, graphing

My Core Plot is almost finished up but I've noticed an unusual thing I need to change before calling it done. The x axis is scaled properly along the bottom, and the left and right edges indicate the range that I've set. The data, however, is all crushed together on the left side, almost as if the y values are not corresponding to their proper x values.

This image should demonstrate what I mean. You'll notice that the dates run along the bottom, but the actual values don't go past the 6/3/11 mark. They should be all the way to the right.

[Link to image](http://www.wesg.ca/photos/graphLine.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the values returned by your datasource. Make sure the x-values are calculated from the same starting date and intervals that you used for the x-axis range and labels.

Comment: That was it, thanks. Turns out my data source was providing X values just incremented according to the index, rather than the date that was supposed to be displayed.